# How to test a post request using xunit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, e2e-testing

I'm new in Asp.net development and I'm having a hard time trying to perform a e2e test. I want to perform a post request and send a json object to my server. The point is that I keep getting an Unsupported Media Type response.

```cs
  public async Task SomeMethod()
  {
    SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass()
    {
      Prop1 = "Prop1",
      Prop2 = "Prop2"
    };

    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass));

    var httpResponse = await _client.PostAsync("/myurl", content);

    httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to set the `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/json`. e.g. `new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: `new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myClass), Encoding.Utf8, "application/json");`

Comment: Thank's a lot. It worked!!!